# How to get terminal windows to span multiple desktops in OSX

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-desktop

When I moved a terminal window from one virtual desktop to another, all of the terminal windows opened move with it to the new desktop. Is there any way to make them go on separate desktops? I am on Snow Leopard.

Comment: How do you move the terminal windows? Do you go to Spaces mode, then move the Windows over that way? Or do you grab one window in one Space, then drag it over to the edge of the screen until it snaps into the new Space? Or do you hold down the mouse button on one window, then press ⌃+arrow key to move it? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: 1: went to spaces mode, and then dragged-n-dropped a terminal window. The second way you described worked for me. Many many thanks!

Comment: Weird. In Spaces mode, only by holding down Shift and dragging a window will it drag all the windows of that application, not otherwise. Not sure what was going on for you in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this can now be accomplished in the latest OSX 10.9 / Mavericks.